# Python calculated 1.0 of type float converts to zero using int()

Tags: python

I am new to python, so I expect that I am missing some basic knowledge of types here.  I am trying to create a string where I take a floating point number and replace decimal point with a string.  In doing so I tried calling a line of code that is equivalent to:

```
int(pow(10, 1)*(5.1%1)))
```

But if you run this code:

```
x = pow(10, 1)*(5.1%1)
print(x)
print(type(x))
print(int(x))
print(int(1.0))
print(type(1.0))
```

It returns:

```
1.0
<type 'float'>
0
1
<type 'float'>
```

I assumed there is a type problem here but they are both type float. So why does int(x) return zero but not int(1.0)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to rounding error, you didn't get exactly 1, but a bit less

```
>>> x = pow(10, 1)*(5.1%1)
>>> print '{:.20f}'.format(x)
0.99999999999999644729
```

You are just getting a bunch of other things rounding up for you when you display it

```
>>> x = pow(10, 1)*(5.1%1)
>>> print x
1.0
>>> print '{:.10f}'.format(x)
1.0000000000
```

To get something displayed that will definitely give the same number (slightly better for debugging), use `repr` out of habit

```
>>> x = pow(10, 1)*(5.1%1)
>>> print repr(x)
0.9999999999999964
>>> print 'hello {!r} world'.format(x)
hello 0.9999999999999964 world
```

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this for me.  I'll round it up.